# Drupal 7 - Views / Geofield - display nodes nearby current node lat / lng

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, coordinates, drupal-views, proximity

I thought this would be a pretty simple thing to do given I have the lat / lng stored in a Geofield. However, I'm really struggling.

Basically I just want to show the 20 nearest nodes to the current node in a block.

No address fields or anything complicated, just straightforward coordinates...

Any ideas before I start hacking?!

BTW, I'm a relative Drupal newbie, but lots of PHP experience.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: OK, this is how far I have got.

I can now get the required list of nearby nodes, BUT only if I enter the coordinates for the filter criteria manually using a geofield-proximity field.

I suppose the question now becomes how do I get the geofield values from my node into the sort filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

- In the contextual filter field add a Geofield proximity filter - something like "Content: Location (field_location) - proximity". Set the radius distance at the bottom.
- Under "When the filter value is NOT available" select "PHP Code"
- Enter the following PHP. The return value is the argument that is passed to the filter.

```
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $value = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_location');
    $lat = $value[0]['lat'];
    $lon= $value[0]['lon'];
    return ($lat . ', ' . $lon);
```

Figured this out from this page https://drupal.org/node/2014345

Answer (score 0):

First install the excellent [location](https://drupal.org/project/location) module.

Add location fields to your results content type and to your main content type.

Create a view based on the main content type (I presume you have this installed) and show as a block.

In the view open advanced filters and in the contextual filters add a filter for "[location distance/proximity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30088/location-distance-based-calculated-field-in-views-results)" is the closest 20 results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I really wanted a Geofield based solution as this is what I am using.